# Is the Following statement is True //false ? .

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is  the Following  statement is True /false ?

Let $G = S_3$ be the permutation group of 3 symbols,then $G$ is a product of cyclic groups?

My attempts : i thinks this  is False  because  G is non commutative

is  it correct ???

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: thanks a lots  @ParclyTaxel..

Comment: more specific: $S_3$ is the semi direct product $\Bbb Z_3\rtimes\Bbb Z_2$